# Room query to retrieve array of matching elements

Tags: android, android-room

Below you can find a small piece of my Room database

[image]

[image]

What I'm triying is to retrieve the list of codes when I pass an array of NameAndPrice.

This is my query:

```
@Query("SELECT Code FROM INGREDIENTS_TABLE WHERE NameAndPrice IN (:userExtraIngredients)")
String[] getIngredientsCodes(String[] userExtraIngredients);
```

But it is always returning empty. 
Any idea about what can be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
 @Query("SELECT Code FROM INGREDIENTS_TABLE WHERE NameAndPrice IN (:userExtraIngredients)")

 List<String> getIngredientsCodes(List<String> userExtraIngredients);
```

and pass obviously a list of strings instead of an array of strings.